# Explicit localization: There a (recommended) size limit for asp.net global resource (resx) language files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, optimization, localization

This is my first time localizing or globalizing anything, so I'm learning on the fly.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 / net4.0 / vb.

As a result of moving my pages into 4 language .resx files located in my App_GlobalResources directory.  I have LocalizedText.resx, fr., .de, and .es-mx.

I'm just about done with it.  But my .resx files are about 120 KB in size.  I don't want to increase loading time, especially on slow or old computers.  Is this too much?  Is this not (recommended)?  I suppose the size has to go somewhere, whether it's in the aspx file or resx file.

I just want to make sure I've been doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an ASP.NET site, the performance will not be so heavily impacted based on the client machine performance. The .resx file will be parsed and compiled into HTML *on the server* before being sent down to the client. The resultant page will be the same size, regardless of how many records you have in the resource file, so the client will not be affected.

That being said, 120KB is not excessive. Depending on the size of the sever, you can get away with much larger resource files, but your performance will vary.

Comment: Thank you very much for that useful information, Joe.  That puts a lot of my concerns at ease now.  I appreciate you taking the time to explain that so clearly!

Answer (score 1):

The size of the .resx file does not affect the size of the page sent to the client.

All of the strings used by the page will be included in the HTML, but if a resource isn't needed it won't be sent.

I have worked on localized applications that included dozens of resx files, totalling megabytes of data, so 120k is not going to be a problem.